# Erro syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, sintaxe

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_form', 10, 2);
function add_search_form($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
        $items .= '<li><div class="sp-search"><div class="top-search"><?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_woocommerce_ajax_search]'); ?></div></div></li>';
        return $items;
}
```

Como posso inserir este shortcode "`<?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_woocommerce_ajax_search]'); ?>`" dentro da div `<div class="top-search">` ... `</div>` corretamente?

Mostra este erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''); ?></div></div></li>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in functions.php on line 137
```

Comment: E qual o erro aparece? Erro de sintaxe existem vários, se puder informar vai facilitar ;)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''); ?></div></div></li>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ...../functions.php on line 137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é nesta linha:

```
$items .= '<li><div class="sp-search"><div class="top-search"><?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_woocommerce_ajax_search]'); ?></div></div></li>';
```

Não se pode colocar PHP dentro de string e nem `echo`, o correto seria concatenar as string, assim:

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
    $items .= '<li><div class="sp-search"><div class="top-search">' .
              do_shortcode('[yith_woocommerce_ajax_search]') .
             '</div></div></li>';

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: tinha tentado concatenar sem o php.. mas tinha esquecido de colocar corretamente as aspas simples. Valeu a ajuda!

Comment: @FabricioCorrêa se resolveu marque a resposta como correta, se não sabe como fazer leia este link http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635, obrigado